# Modified slice elements not accessible with map. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I have a slice of a more or less complex struct and I want all elements of this slice to be accessible with a map. The map contains pointers to the slice elements. My problem is now that when I change the content of a slice element, it is not reflected in the map pointing to this element. I.e. If I access the changed elements from the slice, I see the changes. If I however access the element from my map, I don't see the change.

I made an abstract code example you'll find below. Here it gets even more strange since I see the change in one element although all should be changed.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
    one int
    two *string
}

type List []Test
type MapToList map[int]*Test

func MakeTest() (t List, mt MapToList) {

    t = []Test{}
    mt = make(map[int]*Test)

    var one, two, three string
    one = "one"
    two = "two"
    three = "three"

    t = append(t, Test{1, &one})
    mt[1] = &t[len(t)-1]
    t = append(t, Test{2, &two})
    mt[2] = &t[len(t)-1]
    t = append(t, Test{3, &three})
    mt[3] = &t[len(t)-1]

    return
}

func (s *List) Modify() {
    for index := range *s {
        var str string = "xxx"
        (*s)[index].two = &str
    }
}

func main() {

    t, mt := MakeTest()

    fmt.Println("Orginal")
    for index := range t{
        fmt.Println(index, t[index].one, *t[index].two)
    }

    t.Modify()  

    fmt.Println("Modified List")
    for index := range t{
        fmt.Println(index, t[index].one, *t[index].two)
    }

    fmt.Println("Modified Map")
    for key, value := range mt {
        fmt.Println(key, value.one, *value.two)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Orginal
0 1 one
1 2 two
2 3 three
Modified List
0 1 xxx
1 2 xxx
2 3 xxx
Modified Map
1 1 one
2 2 two
3 3 xxx
```

Comment: Could you also post your expected output?

Comment: The expected output under "Modified Map" should be "xxx" for 1, 2 and 3. Similar to the output under "Modified List".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just consistently use pointers in slices and maps. That simplifies a lot.

As you are using slices of values, it happens that `&t[i]` after `append` operation becomes a pointer to an element in the old discarded slice. When you accessing it you are accessing the element of the old slice. Therefore map is referencing an element of a old slice.

Using pointers solves the problem because there is only one copy of each `Test` structure and multiple pointers to them. It does not matter whether the pointers are in old slice, new slice or map.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
    one int
    two *string
}

type List []*Test
type MapToList map[int]*Test

func MakeTest() (t List, mt MapToList) {

    t = []*Test{}
    mt = make(map[int]*Test)

    var one, two, three string
    one = "one"
    two = "two"
    three = "three"

    t = append(t, &Test{1, &one})
    mt[1] = t[len(t)-1]
    t = append(t, &Test{2, &two})
    mt[2] = t[len(t)-1]
    t = append(t, &Test{3, &three})
    mt[3] = t[len(t)-1]

    return
}

func (s *List) Modify() {
    for index := range *s {
        var str string = "xxx"
        (*s)[index].two = &str
    }
}

func main() {

    t, mt := MakeTest()

    fmt.Println("Orginal")
    for index := range t{
        fmt.Println(index, t[index].one, *t[index].two)
    }

    t.Modify()  

    fmt.Println("Modified List")
    for index := range t{
        fmt.Println(index, t[index].one, *t[index].two)
    }

    fmt.Println("Modified Map")
    for key, value := range mt {
        fmt.Println(key, value.one, *value.two)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KvG3Mj4v1u

The output is

```
Orginal
0 1 one
1 2 two
2 3 three
Modified List
0 1 xxx
1 2 xxx
2 3 xxx
Modified Map
1 1 xxx
2 2 xxx
3 3 xxx
```